# mysql function to update all rows in table A when table B updated

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have searched high and low for an answer but to no avail - it maybe because what I am asking is not possible ?

I thought a trigger calling a stored procedure might be the way forward ......

So, the question:

I have a table markup that holds just one record, an integer, lets say 10. 

In table products each row has a number of columns including a price.

What I would like is for each row from table products to be updated with newPrice when the markup record changes, ie:

Calculate costPrice x markup = newPrice now update each row in table products

Hope that makes sense ?

Comment: A simple trigger should do that. But I wouldn't do that at all.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Spiegel. Could you clarify both your comments please ? Can you steer me in the right direction as to how I accomplish this task using a trigger ? Why would this action not be good practice ?

Comment: I just can't imagine a good reason for such trigger. The same can be done with a simple update statement on the `products` table. What a trigger is doing and why, should be obvious. This is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks again @PaulSpiegel. I am keen to learn and do try to research solutions online (infact this is the first time I have been beaten and succumbed to asking my Q in this forum) 
I understand the make up of a simple `UPDATE table SET tempPrice = newPrice` statement, but cannot get my head round how I can amend the updated column (tempPrice) with a different value in each row (value being calculated by `costPrice * markup = newPrice`) ?

Comment: `UPDATE mytable SET tempPrice = costPrice * 0.85` - `0.85` is your "markaup" value here.